# php configuration cannot find -lmysqlclient

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to configure a PHP installation (5.4.3) with MYSQL (5.0.91) for use with a PHP web application that relies on the MDB2 mysql module.  When I install using PEAR, pear tells me that PHP does not have the required mysql extension.

Some googling around lead me to check the PHP.ini file, in which I found that extension=php_mysql.dll was commented out.  I turned this on and restarted php.  PHP complains that it can't find php_mysql.dll.

I realized that this might have been because I didn't install php with the --with-sql flag turned on.  Reconfiguring leaves me with the following error:

```
checking for MySQL support... yes
checking for specified location of the MySQL UNIX socket... /project/mullenl
checking for mysql_close in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for mysql_errno in -lmysqlclient... no
configure: error: Try adding --with-zlib-dir=<DIR>. Please check config.log for more information.
```

A quick look at the configuration log shows the problem:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient
```

When I check my lib directory in my mysql installation the following things are present:

```
libdbug.a   
libmysql.imp      
libmysqlclient.so*     
libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0*      
libmysqlclient_r.so*     
libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0*  
libmysys.a      
libndbclient.la*  
libndbclient.so.2*
libmygcc.a  
libmysqlclient.a  
libmysqlclient.so.15*  
libmysqlclient_r.a         
libmysqlclient_r.so.15*  
libmystrings.a               
libndbclient.a  
libndbclient.so*  
libndbclient.so.2.0.0*
```

I'm not too sure what to do next, but really need to configure PHP in this way to support the MDB2:MYSQL module.  I suspect (?) that the reason I can't do this is because I don't have the development version of MYSQL installed, but I'm not sure this is the case.  Any thoughts, ideas or advise would, as always, be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Any reason you're compiling your own php install? why not use one of the *amp packages?

Comment: good question.  I'm asking myself that now.  I have NGINX serving the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `php_mysql.dll` extension is only used on Windows, it looks like you are on Unix/Linux.

If you view your `phpinfo()`, what are your configure options?

You can build mysql into PHP by adding `--with-mysql=mysqlnd` to your `./configure` options.

If you have a custom version of mysql that is compiled on the system, then specify the path to where it is installed instead of using the mysql native driver (mysqlnd) `--with-mysql=/usr/lib`

Comment: Drew- I did use the --with-mysql pointing to my mysql compiled directory, that's what's giving the error.

Comment: OK, the **--with-mysql=mysqlnd** seemes to have gotten mysql working on PHP.  However, I've lost my ability to use PEAR.  It seems to be looking in a nonexistent directory when I call PEAR from the command line.

Comment: Make sure pear is installed in your path, or call it using the full path which is `PREFIX/lib/php` (default prefix is /usr/local) but you can specify it by using `--prefix=/path`

Comment: OK, fixed it. that was my bad.  The --with-mysql=mysqlnd was the appropriate flag to use for my setup, rather than the old connector flag --with-mysql=/usr/lib.  Thanks Drew!